# Largest eigenvalue being negative

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Can anyone please tell me what can I know about a square matrix that has only non-positive eigenvalues.

In a text book I read it says that lets suppose matrix A has only non-positive eigenvalues then 
 $$  A  \preccurlyeq \mathbf{0} $$

I thought it meant it each of its element is less than 0 but that is not true.

Comment: You should provide some more context and some of your ideas.

Comment: Check [positive definite and negative definite definitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix).

Answer (score 1):

The notation you used to compare $A$ to $0$ is often used for symmetric matrices, and it means the matrix is negative semi-definite, which means $x^TAx \leq 0$ for all vectors $x$. This does not mean all entries are non-positive but it does mean that the diagonal is all non-positive.

Comment: Thank you so much! That clears my confusion!